# Centre of Mass in x,y plane

Tags: calculus, integration

Given an area $R$ in x,y plane, and the density is $\rho(x,y)$ at $(x,y)$, then we can use double integrals to calculate the centre of mass coordinates. Now my question is, intuitively, given any non-zero vector, and draw a line through centre of mass we divide the area into two pieces.

How to calculate mass of these two pieces separately? Because I think the mass of these two pieces are equal so I want to compare these two.

Comment: There's no reason to think the two pieces have equal mass. Take the case where $R$ is just three equal point masses at corners of a rectangle. Most lines through the center of mass will have two of these points in one piece, and only one in the other.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, it makes sense.